# Нужно изменить громкость звука в режиме реального времени pyglet

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyglet

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы пользователь мог менять громкость в режиме прослушивания.Не могу понять как сделать так в pyglet

```
import os
import pyglet

count = 1

dir = (os.path.abspath('music'))

print(os.listdir(dir))

music_files = list(filter(lambda x: x.endswith('.mp3'), os.listdir(dir)))

for i in music_files:
    print(f'{count}.{i[:-4]}')
    count += 1

input_user = int(input('Какой трек нужно включить?\n'))

while input_user != '5':
    mus = pyglet.resource.media(f'music/{music_files[input_user-1]}')
    mus.play()
    input_user = input('1.Изменить громкость\n2.Включить другой трек\n3.Сл.трек\n4.Пред.трек\n5.Стоп')
    pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: Попробуй перед `mus.play()` написать `mus.volume = 0.5`

Comment: уже пробовал, не работает

Comment: Скинул пример кода, надеюсь, поможет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В качестве примера скину код с настройкой громкости:

Импорт библиотеки:

```
from pyglet.resource import media
from pyglet.media import Player
```

Настройка звука:

```
music = resource.media('sounds/ride-the-storm.ogg')
music_player = Player()
music_player.queue(music)
music_player.volume = 0.5
music_player.play()
```

Comment: спасибо тебе!после чтения документации сам не смог понять как сделать